# How to validate a email address domain in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-validation

In Laravel, how do I validate an email address and force it to have a suffix like `g.go.edu`?

Comment: Are you using laravel 4 or 5? You can't be using both...

Comment: I have reworded the question and title to make it easier to read.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel:custom validation for email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933019/laravelcustom-validation-for-email)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to accept all emails that have suffix `g.go.edu`, you can use as rule both `email` and `regex` rules, for example:

```
$rules['email'] = ['email', 'regex:/(.*)g\.go\.edu$/i'];
```