# Validate email domain in Laravel request

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-validation

I want to accept email from just one server when someone is registering, for example "@myemail.com". If any other email address is given it will say your email is not valid.

Below is the validator of my registration controller. What should I do?

```php
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        /*'usertype' => 'required',*/
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a regex pattern for this. Append this to your email validation:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|regex:/(.*)@myemail\.com/i|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        /*'usertype' => 'required',*/
     ]);
}
```

**EDIT**
With mutiple domains you have to use an array with your validations, because of the pipe between the two mail domains:

```
'email' => ['required', 'max:255', 'email', 'regex:/(.*)@(mrbglobalbd|millwardbrown)\.com/i', 'unique:users'],
```

> Note: When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

Comment: what if i want to verify for 2 mailserver type id's `myemail` and `myemail2` ?? where should i add that??

Comment: You could update the pattern and include multiple domains in brakets. I've updated my answer.

Comment: it shows error `ErrorException in Validator.php line 1798:
preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found`

Comment: @incorporeal please show your code `'email' => '...`

Comment: here it is `'email' => 'required|email|max:255|regex:/(.*)@(mrbglobalbd|millwardbrown)\.com/i|unique:users' `

Comment: @incorporeal sorry, my bad. If you use a pipe in the regex you have to use an array instead.

Answer (score 6):

**since laravel 5.8.17** `ends_with` validation rule was added, which looks like this:

```
$rules = [
    'email' => 'required|ends_with:laravel.com,jasonmccreary.me,gmail.com',
];
```

Comment: I'd suggest `ends_with:@laravel.com...` to be safe, and also keep the `email` rule in place.

Answer (score 2):

Please do the following change in your email validation line. You can expand the email validation in your validator rule like:

```
protected function validator(array $data){
  $messages = array('email.regex' => 'Your email id is not valid.');

  return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users|regex:/(.*)\.myemail\.com$/i',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    /*'usertype' => 'required',*/
 ], $messages);}
```