# How to validate special type of content in email in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to give access only for `@gmail.com` address, but not for `@outlook.com` address. How to code this logic in laravel.

```
'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],//this is my email  validation code
```

Comment: It can be done by adding `'regex:/(.+)@gmail\.com/i'`

Comment: got the answer pindev thank you..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an Email in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855811/how-to-validate-an-email-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720750/how-to-validate-a-email-address-domain-in-laravel)

you can do something like

```
$rules['email'] = ['email', 'regex:/(.*)\@gmail\.com$/i'];
```